# How do I stop apps resize when moved between two different monitors - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a secondary, 24" monitor together with my Dell laptop's own display (Precision M4700 - i7 Ivy Bridge + AMD FirePro M4000). When I work at home, the larger monitor is set as primary monitor. They are different resolutions, Laptop is FHD, the external 1680x1050.

However, when I move a window from the bigger (external-24") to the laptop's display, Windows tries to maintain the relatively same size instead of just showing the window smaller. This occurs whenever I move a window at least 40-50% to the other monitor. How do I stop that ? It's very annoying. It doesn't seem related to multitasking settings, snap is disabled.

This occurred since I reinstalled Windows 10 (November 2019 official ISO). At the same time, after last BIOS update (A19), November too, the system doesn't see anymore the integrated graphics (HD 4000), doesn't matter if I check that in Windows or in BIOS.

On the other hand, when I use a Dell Latitude E5520 laptop, i7 2670qm, Sandy-Bridge, integrated graphics only (HD 3000), I don't have any issues so, even it's not as powerful as Precision, my workflow on it is much more fluent.

When I'm on the field, at some clients and I want to connect another, bigger display, but I really need both monitors, this issue becomes really embarrassing.

Please help, I don't know what to do anymore. Thanks !

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

The problem was under Display settings -> Scale and Layout 
(change the size of text, apps and other items)

Scale was set differently on the two monitors:

The external was set (by default?) 100% (1680x1050, 24").

The laptop was set to 125% (1920x1080, 15")

I put them both on the same scaling (100%) and everything works fine !
(Tested in 125% on both too, but on the 24" all items appears ridiculously big !! Reversed to 100%)

Thanks anyway !

:)